# Prolog Facts and Rules in Use

Tags: prolog

Today is my second day in learning Prolog.
I don't know a lot about Prolog.
I have a file with this facts/rules.

```
mother(X,Y):-
    parent(X,Y),
    female(X).
son(X,Y):-
    parent(Y,X),
    male(X).
daughter(X,Y):-
    parent(Y,X),
    female(X).
grandmother(X,Y):-
    parent(Z,Y),
    parent(X,Z),
    female(X).
```

and

```
son(a,b).
daughter(b,c).
```

I can question

```
?- mother(b,a).
?- parent(b,a).
?- grandmother(c,a).
```

of Prolog.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Excuse if my english is so bad, I can question from prolog that who is mother of a?

Comment: Your English seems fine, I just don't see what your question is. What do you want to know?

Comment: if i say a is son of b, and b and b is female, prolog can say me that b is mother of a??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand.

Do you want deduce (1) that `b` is mother of `a`, (2) that `b` is parent of `a` and (3) that `c` is grandmother of `a` starting *only* from the facts that (a) `a` is son of `b` and (b) that `b` is daughter of `c` ?

In this case, it seems to me that you can deduce (1) and (2) from the following facts and rules

```
son(a, b).
daughter(b, c).

female(X) :-
   daughter(X, _).

parent(X, Y) :-
   son(Y, X).

mother(X, Y) :-
   female(X),
   parent(X, Y).
```

And don't know how to deduce (3) (`c` is grandmother of `a`) because I can deduce that `c` is grandparent of `a` but I don't know how to deduce that `c` is female.

Adding the fact `female(c)` and a rule `grandmother` (plus a rule for `parent` deriving from `daughter`), you can deduce (3) with the following fact and rules.

```
son(a, b).
daughter(b, c).
female(c).

female(X) :-
  daughter(X, _).

parent(X, Y) :-
  son(Y, X).

parent(X, Y) :-
  daughter(Y, X).

mother(X, Y) :-
  female(X),
  parent(X, Y).

grandmother(X, Z):-
  mother(X, Y),
  parent(Y, Z).
```

Other solutions are possibles.

Answer (score 0):

Does son(a,b) mean a is the son of b or b is the son of a?  Prolog doesn't care, but you have to make up your mind how you're using it.

I think it means b is the son of a.  That, however, is not a fact about Prolog.  It is just my guess of what somebody meant.

Now, do you have the information to tell you who is the mother of a?

If you ask
?- mother(Z, a).
it will use the definition of mother to try to satisfy
?- female(Z), parent(Z,a).
Now it will use the definition of female to change this to:
?- daughter(Z,_), parent(Z,a).
It will use the fact daughter(b,c) to satisfy daughter with Z=b.
Then the rest of the query is:
?- parent(b,a).
But we're not done.  Is b in fact a parent of a?
There are two definitions of parent.  So, try the first one,
changing the query to:
?- son(a,b).
Success -- That matches a fact.
So the answer to ?- mother(Z,a). is Z=b.

The things to remember about how Prolog works are:

- It always has a list of one or more queries that have to be satisfied in succession;

  - It looks for a fact or rule that will match the first query in that list;
- When it uses a rule, it turns the first query in the list into one or more queries to replace it;
- When it uses a fact, it simply makes the first query in the list disappear (by matching it to a fact), and that's how the list eventually becomes empty.
- When there is more than one rule or fact that will match a query, Prolog tries the first one that matches, but remembers what the next one was.  If it cannot eventually satisfy all the queries, it backs up to the MOST RECENT UNTRIED ALTERNATIVE.

When I was teaching Prolog, I had the whole class recite, out loud, "MOST RECENT UNTRIED ALTERNATIVE" because that is the thing you must always remember.

This may be useful:

http://www.covingtoninnovations.com/books/PPID.pdf